# Array Binding for Select Statement in dbms_sql (Oracle 11g)

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, bind-variables

My Problem is that I want to execute a dynamic SQL-Query within PL/SQL where I have a List of IDs as my Array Bind. 
In the Oracle-Documentation I found some Examples how to join Lists of Numbers to an DML-Statement. (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm#i996963)

Now I am trying to make the same thing for Select-Statements.
I know that I can use Array-Binds for the `execute immediate-Statement`. But this has the disadvantage that I must know the exact number of Bind-Variables before executing the Statement. That is the reason why I have to use dbms_sql.

The following Example Returns only one Row, but it should return 3 rows. Does anyone know what the Problem with my Example is?

```
--TestData:
CREATE TABLE PERSON AS
SELECT LEVEL AS ID, 'Person_'||LEVEL AS NAME
FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;

declare
    p_ids dbms_sql.number_table;
    c number; 
    dummy NUMBER;
    p_name varchar2(100);
begin
    p_ids(1) := 2;
    p_ids(2) := 3;
    p_ids(3) := 4;
    --
    c := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(c, 'select name from PERSON where id in(:num_array)', DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);   
    dbms_sql.define_column(c, 1, p_name, 100); 
    DBMS_SQL.BIND_ARRAY(c, ':num_array', p_ids);    
    dummy := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(c);
    --
    loop
        exit when dbms_sql.fetch_rows(c) <=0;
        dbms_sql.column_value(c, 1, p_name);
        dbms_output.put_line(p_name);
    end loop;
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(c);
end;
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware Oracle does not provide a facility for binding an array to an `IN` value list. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current solution for binding multiple values to a Select Statement, maybe someone can need it:

```
--TestData:
CREATE TABLE PERSON AS
SELECT LEVEL AS ID, 'Person_'||LEVEL AS NAME
FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;

declare
    c number; 
    dummy NUMBER;
    p_name varchar2(100);
    xml$ varchar2(1000);
begin
    --Generate a XML-List instead of dbms_sql.number_table:
    xml$ := '<ids><id>2</id><id>3</id><id>4</id></ids>';
    --
    c := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    --Using XML-Functions for extracting the Values from the XML-String
    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(c, 'select name 
                         from PERSON 
                        where id in(select extractvalue(value(x), ''id'')
                                      from table(xmlsequence(xmltype(:ids).extract(''ids/*'')))x)'
                       , DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);   
    dbms_sql.define_column(c, 1, p_name, 100); 
    DBMS_SQL.BIND_variable(c, ':ids', xml$);    
    dummy := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(c);
    --
    loop
        exit when dbms_sql.fetch_rows(c) <=0;
        dbms_sql.column_value(c, 1, p_name);
        dbms_output.put_line(p_name);
    end loop;
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(c);
end;
```